# How add a mask using svg .net?

Tags: c#, .net, svg, line, mask

I don't know how to add a mask to a line using svg .net like this:

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
    <mask id="myMask">`
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="white" />
    <rect x="170" y="150" width="50" height="50" fill="white" />
    </mask>      
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:gray;stroke-width:2" stroke-dasharray="5, 5" />
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:blue;stroke-width:2"  mask="url(#myMask)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Was looking for this quite a time, thanks for sharing. This one works with SVG.NET, the main issue for me was URI part and not adding clipping stuff to the SvgGroup ...

Answer (score 1):

I did it like this. The area in the clip would be the part visible.

```
 var rectangle = new SvgPolygon();
            var group = new SvgGroup();

            var clip2 = new SvgClipPath
            {
                ID = "Clip2",
                Children =
                {
                    new SvgRectangle()
                    {
                        X = 0,
                        Y = 0,
                        Width = 40,
                        Height = 40
                    }
                }
            };

            group.Children.Add(clip2);
            group.Children.Add(rectangle);
            rectangle.ClipPath =  new Uri("url(#Clip2)", UriKind.Relative);
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">

<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" width="989" height="162" viewBox="0, 0, 100, 100">  
  <g stroke-width="1" font-family="Roboto" font-size="8" font="Roboto" fill-opacity="0" groupName="TopChord" style="stroke:black;">
    <g>
      <clipPath id="Clip2">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="40" height="40" />
      </clipPath>
      <polygon points="10,20 10,60 90,60 90,20" clip-path="url(#Clip2)" id="0" stroke-width="1" fill-opacity="1" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This looks like a clipPath rather than a mask. Did you mean this to be part of the question? If so you should edit it into the question and delete this as it doesn't seem to be an answer to your question.